# WCF client certificate authentication from Invoke-WebRequest on the same host

Tags: c#, powershell, wcf, ssl, client-certificates

I have a WebServer WCF .NET4.6.2 application running of a Windows Server. I want to call API of that WebServer from within the same server only, for that matter the firewall blocks port of my WebServer. Also I want to allow WebServer API calls from users with Administrator privileges only. For that matter I thought certificate authentication would do the trick. My WCF service setup is

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:2000/");
var binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
var endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(MyWebApi)),
    binding,
    new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));    
webServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(kernel.Get<MyWebApi>(), baseAddress);
webServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint);
webServiceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;
webServiceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
webServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;
webServiceHost.Open();
```

I have created a root certificate, and put it into LocalComputer\Trusted Root CA.

I have created an intermediate certificate and put into into LocalComputer\Intermediate CA.

I have created two [certificate + private key] - with names "localhost" and "client".

I've put "localhost" to LocalComputer\Personal

I've put "client" to LocalComputer\Personal and to MyUser\Trusted People.

My WebServer runs as MyUser. I registered my webserver to use SSL.

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:2000 certhash="hash of localhost" appid="{00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}"  clientcertnegotiation=enable
```

I'm trying to run the following command on the same host where my WebServer is running using MyUser

```
Invoke-WebRequest -method post -uri https://localhost:2000/ping -CertificateThumbprint "hash of client"
```

But what I get is

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Fiddler shows the response

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

Changing binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType to HttpClientCredentialType.None works, and proofs that my client can verify my webserver's certificate, but I can't figure out why the webserver can't verify clients certificate.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: About Transport Security with Certificate Authentication you can refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication

Comment: You need to make sure that the server trusts the client's certificate.

Comment: For how to make the machine trust the certificate, you can refer to this link:https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Trusting-an-SSL-Certificate-on-a-Client-Machine

Comment: @DingPeng There are two validations
1 - the client validates if it could trust the server, in my case "localhost" certificate was issued by my intermediate CA, that was issues by my root CA. I've added intermediate CA and root CA to corresponding folders in the Trust Store, not sure how else servers certificate can be trusted
2 - the server validates if it could trust the client. my "client" certificate was issued by the same intermediate CA as above. And I've added "client" certificate to Trusted People. 
Apparently I did something wrong, but what exactly?

Comment: You can use this code to avoid validating the certificate "ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;".

Comment: Actually my server has to validate clients certificate, so that non-admin user can't call my webserver API.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I was missing two things:

1. I had to deploy a Certificate Revocation List for my Root CA
2. I had to create a client certificate that includes Intended Purposes "Client Authentication"